# Can't start program through Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I am trying to start a command when I log on through remote desktop connection. The program is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -r -t 00 -c "Unresponsive Program"
```

I set the program option under the Programs tab in remote desktop connection to that path. It looks like this:[image]

However, when I connect to the remote machine I get this error: "The system cannot find the file specified"

[image]

I have made sure my shutdown.exe file exists, and also tried running `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, and I got the same error message. I am running Windows Server 2012 on the host and Windows 8 on the client. What is causing this problem?